# Org mode elisp in :var in header-args causing max-specpdl-size error

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In org mode, `:var` header arg definitions can actually call other `SRC` blocks, which is very nice! However I've run into a problem exemplified by the following org file:

```
#+NAME: add3
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var num=0
(+ 3 num)
#+END_SRC

* Use function drawer header arg
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :var n=add3(5)
:END:

#+NAME: whatIsN
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
echo $n
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: whatIsN
: 8

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var a=whatIsN
echo $a
#+END_SRC

# !!!!ERROR!!!!: "variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size"
```

This exact same example works fine if the `:var` for `n` is defined inline (instead of in the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer), like:

```
#+NAME: whatIsN
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :var n=add3(5)
echo $n
#+END_SRC
```

Anyone know what's causing org mode to stumble when the `:var` is defined in the `:PROPERTIES:` section?

**org-version** 9.1.11

Comment: There is some sort of infinite recursion going on. If you `toggle-debug-on-error` you'll see that org-babel get's stuck parsing the expression n=add3(5).

Comment: The problem is fixed in [the current `master` of orgmode](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/04641c4bbefc5f90e05fe4e846f4aeab15f1c262/lisp/ob-core.el#L1446) but not in the [`maint` branch of orgmode](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/1315315465d49ebe32e533515ec81fd1ba165a55/lisp/ob-core.el#L1444).

Comment: Did you test org-version 9.1.14? The problematic bit is still present in that branch of the org repository. (See the edit at the end of my answer.) I just did update and test. In spite of what Charles said: org 9.1.14 has the same problem.

Comment: Yup, just tested 9.1.14 and the same error happens, as you say.

Comment: I just tried this again in org mode 9.2.2 and it is indeed fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is located in `org-babel-get-src-block-info`.

The function `org-babel-params-from-properties` is used there. Its doc-string is:

> Retrieve parameters specified as properties.
>   Return a list of association lists of source block params
>   specified in the properties of the current outline entry.

But they do not say what the current outline entry is. In `org-babel-get-src-block-info` they assumed that the current outline entry would be that one at point but `org-babel-params-from-properties` uses also `org-babel-current-src-block-location` to retrieve parameters from there.

Even if `(point)` is 1 for the first source block `add3` the variable `org-babel-current-src-block-location` in `org-babel-params-from-properties` points to the source block `whatIsN`.

So not the `header-args` for `add3` are collected by `org-babel-params-from-properties` but those of `whatIsN`.

The consequence is that `add3` gets the header arg `n=add3(5)` from the drawer. Naturally, that leads to infinite recursion.

The funny thing is that they already tried to make sure that `org-babel-params-from-properties` gets the right header args from the location of `datum`.
I cite a small section of `org-babel-get-src-block-info`:

```el
           ;; If DATUM is provided, make sure we get node
           ;; properties applicable to its location within
           ;; the document.
           (org-with-point-at (org-element-property :begin datum)
             (org-babel-params-from-properties lang))
```

You can avoid the error if you additionally `let`-bind `org-babel-current-src-block-location` to the location of `datum`:

```el
           ;; If DATUM is provided, make sure we get node
           ;; properties applicable to its location within
           ;; the document.
           (let ((org-babel-current-src-block-location (org-element-property :begin datum)))
             (org-with-point-at org-babel-current-src-block-location
               (org-babel-params-from-properties lang)))
```

I am not sure about the full consequences of that change through.

Note that I sent a bug-report to emacs-orgmode@gnu.org.

---

**EDIT:** I already got a response on emacs-orgmode@gnu.org from Charles Berry. He wrote that he could not reproduce the problem on Orgmode 9.1.14.

I had a [quick look at the current master of the orgmode repository](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/04641c4bbefc5f90e05fe4e846f4aeab15f1c262/lisp/ob-core.el#L1446). They fixed the bug by substituting the reference to `org-babel-current-src-block-location` with `(point)` in `org-babel-params-from-properties`.

Nevertheless, the [problem is still present in the current maint branch of orgmode](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/1315315465d49ebe32e533515ec81fd1ba165a55/lisp/ob-core.el#L1444).

The problematic reference of `org-babel-current-src-block-location` within `org-babel-params-from-properties` is even present [in the `release_9.14` branch of orgmode](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/release_9.1.14/lisp/ob-core.el#L1439). In spite of what Charles said.

Comment: This is fantastic! You are awesome Tobias.